# Is it possible, as business profile, to get data about followers (age,city) and post reach via Instagram API?

Tags: facebook, api, oauth, instagram, instagram-api

It is possible now to get via Instagram API data like: single post reach, data about our Ads on instagram, data about our followers (age, city, country) and all data that we can see in instagram insights?

Or maybe it is possible to get Facebook user ID of our Instagram follower?

Comment: You can of course not get Facebook User ID of Instagram followers

Answer (score 0):

- Using API you can get a post's reach - number of likes and comments.
- Currently there is no API to get data about Ads.  You can get followers list and their photos via API, but not their age/city/country.
- No API for insights.
- You cannot get facebook ID of Instagram followers.

Documentation for Instagram API is here, it shows whats possible currently:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/